# Is it OK to use Facebook photos in our web apps?

Tags: facebook, photo, policy

I'd like to offer my users the capability of either uploading a photo, or choosing one of their photos on Facebook (not only their profile photo).

Pulling the photo source from the Graph API isn't hard... However, does Facebook authorize us to use their photo link source in our apps, or must we download the photo, store it on our servers, and source them from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a lawyer but it seems pretty clear either method is fine according to their [developer policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/).  Specifically 2.2 states:

> You may cache data you receive through use of the Facebook API in
>   order to improve your application’s user experience, but you should
>   try to keep the data up to date. This permission does not give you any
>   rights to such data.

My only concern would be the privacy settings on the photos and whether people would be able to access it via Facebook's url.  But if you test it and it works and if the user explicitly selects the photo themselves, that would seem to be fine and wouldn't be much difference then them re-uploading it to your site.

Comment: Yea, that block of text you quoted, was the only thing I could find about using their data. It sounds to me like we can use it either way, but caching is better performance.

And yes, I agree about the privacy controls. A third party may not be able to see it. I wonder if I can query the Graph API only for the user's photos which are publicly accessible? 

Thx!

Answer (score 2):

The safest bet is certainly to download the photo and save it yourself; as with web links I wouldn't trust that a photo link will be valid later.

That said, you then have to deal with deleted/removed photos and cleaning them up in your application.